# CSS Dropdown Submenu issue

Tags: html, css

Hi guys i am working on a Menu item. The menu has some Sub Menus within some li's.
I am showing the dropdown menu when corresponding parent li has been hovered.but i am getting issues like while hovering over location's sub menu ,i am getting user profile sub menu and also same like hovering over notification submenu, user profile dropdown is showing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Compiled and minified Materialize CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        header {
            width: 100%;
            height: 64px;
            background-color: #31373d;
            color: #fff;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding-top: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }
        
        header .header-inner {
            width: 95%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        
        header .cafe-logo {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 2.1rem;
        }
        /****** Styles for the Desktop Tab only topbar menu ********/
        
        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav {
            float: right;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav>li {
            width: 38px;
            height: 64px;
            line-height: 64px;
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        
        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav>li>a {
            color: #fff;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav>li>a:hover {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        
        header .notification-badge {
            position: absolute;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 20px;
            font-size: 12px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            color: #fff;
            top: 5px;
            left: 12px;
        }
        
        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav>li:hover>ul {
            height: auto !important;
            opacity: 1 !important;
        }
        /***** Styles for the Sub Menu *********/
        
        #locations-list {
            display: block;
            opacity: 0;
            height: 0;
            width: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 61px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            transition: all 300ms;
            line-height: normal;
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        }
        
        #locations-list li a {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        #notifications-list {
            height: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            position: absolute;
            width: 280px;
            top: 61px;
            left: 0;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
            line-height: normal;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        #notifications-list li a {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        }
        
        #notifications-list .notification-icon-wrapper {
            padding: 5px 8px;
            color: #fff;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-right: 20px;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
        
        #profile-dropdown-nav {
            margin: 0;
            width: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 60px;
            transition: all 300ms;
            opacity: 0;
            height: 0;
        }
        
        #profile-dropdown-nav li a {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        }
        
        #profile-dropdown-nav li a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        #profile-dropdown-nav li:hover {
            background-color: #f1f2f6;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header id="header" class="header navbar-fixed clearfix">
        <div class="header-inner">
            <a href="index.php" title="Norbotion" class="cafe-logo">
                Norbotion
            </a>
            <ul id="desktop-tab-only-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">location_on</i>
                        <span class="notification-badge red">3</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="locations-list" class="collection with-header locations-list active">
                        <li class="collection-header">
                            <span class="new badge" data-badge-caption="">3</span>
                            <span style="font-weight: bold;padding-left: 10px"> Locations </span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Shollinganallur </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Taramani </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Karapakkam </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">mail</i>
                        <span class="notification-badge orange"> 4 </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">notifications</i>
                        <span class="notification-badge pink">5</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="notifications-list" class="collection with-header notifications-list active">
                        <li class="collection-header">
                            <p>
                                <span class="new badge">5</span> NOTIFICATIONS </p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper cyan">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span> New Zomoto Order palced
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper red">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span>New Zomoto Order palced
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper teal">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span>New Takeaway Order palced
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper deep-orange">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span>New Zomoto Order palced
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper amber">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span> New Uber Eat Order palced
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="profile-dropdown-nav" class="collection profile-dropdown-nav">
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="clearfix">
                                <i class="material-icons left">tag_faces</i>
                                <span> User profile </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="clearfix">
                                <i class="material-icons left">lock_outline</i>
                                <span> Logout </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Not sure what is the issue. guys please help on this

[image]

Comment: The snippet you provided seems to be working fine, in that only the hovered items sub-menu is showing. Am I missing something here?

Comment: when you hover over the location submenu, user profile submenu is showing

Answer (score 0):

Actually Now I am seeing your document height smaller than the window, When Your hover some icon then dropdown open and document height greater than window height then scrollbar showing.

**Solutions:** ***you add some content after the header, like this here..***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Compiled and minified Materialize CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        header {
            width: 100%;
            height: 64px;
            background-color: #31373d;
            color: #fff;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding-top: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }
        
        header .header-inner {
            width: 95%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        
        header .cafe-logo {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 2.1rem;
        }
        /****** Styles for the Desktop Tab only topbar menu ********/
        
        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav {
            float: right;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav>li {
            width: 38px;
            height: 64px;
            line-height: 64px;
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        
        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav>li>a {
            color: #fff;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav>li>a:hover {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        
        header .notification-badge {
            position: absolute;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 20px;
            font-size: 12px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            color: #fff;
            top: 5px;
            left: 12px;
        }
        
        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav>li:hover>ul {
            height: auto !important;
            opacity: 1 !important;
        }
        /***** Styles for the Sub Menu *********/
        
        #locations-list {
            display: block;
            opacity: 0;
            height: 0;
            width: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 61px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            transition: all 300ms;
            line-height: normal;
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        }
        
        #locations-list li a {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        #notifications-list {
            height: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            position: absolute;
            width: 280px;
            top: 61px;
            left: 0;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
            line-height: normal;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        #notifications-list li a {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        }
        
        #notifications-list .notification-icon-wrapper {
            padding: 5px 8px;
            color: #fff;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-right: 20px;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
        
        #profile-dropdown-nav {
            margin: 0;
            width: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 60px;
            transition: all 300ms;
            opacity: 0;
            height: 0;
        }
        
        #profile-dropdown-nav li a {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        }
        
        #profile-dropdown-nav li a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        #profile-dropdown-nav li:hover {
            background-color: #f1f2f6;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header id="header" class="header navbar-fixed clearfix">
        <div class="header-inner">
            <a href="index.php" title="Norbotion" class="cafe-logo">
                Norbotion
            </a>
            <ul id="desktop-tab-only-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">location_on</i>
                        <span class="notification-badge red">3</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="locations-list" class="collection with-header locations-list active">
                        <li class="collection-header">
                            <span class="new badge" data-badge-caption="">3</span>
                            <span style="font-weight: bold;padding-left: 10px"> Locations </span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Shollinganallur </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Taramani </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Karapakkam </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">mail</i>
                        <span class="notification-badge orange"> 4 </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">notifications</i>
                        <span class="notification-badge pink">5</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="notifications-list" class="collection with-header notifications-list active">
                        <li class="collection-header">
                            <p>
                                <span class="new badge">5</span> NOTIFICATIONS </p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper cyan">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span> New Zomoto Order palced
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper red">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span>New Zomoto Order palced
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper teal">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span>New Takeaway Order palced
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper deep-orange">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span>New Zomoto Order palced
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper amber">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span> New Uber Eat Order palced
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="profile-dropdown-nav" class="collection profile-dropdown-nav">
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="clearfix">
                                <i class="material-icons left">tag_faces</i>
                                <span> User profile </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="clearfix">
                                <i class="material-icons left">lock_outline</i>
                                <span> Logout </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section>
        <h1>title</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section





</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can accomplish that using z-index, now the user profile sub menu will not popup while hover on other things.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Compiled and minified Materialize CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        header {
            width: 100%;
            height: 64px;
            background-color: #31373d;
            color: #fff;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding-top: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }
        
        header .header-inner {
            width: 95%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        
        header .cafe-logo {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 2.1rem;
        }
        /****** Styles for the Desktop Tab only topbar menu ********/
        
        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav {
            float: right;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav>li {
            width: 38px;
            height: 64px;
            line-height: 64px;
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        
        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav>li>a {
            color: #fff;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav>li>a:hover {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        
        header .notification-badge {
            position: absolute;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 20px;
            font-size: 12px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            color: #fff;
            top: 5px;
            left: 12px;
        }
        #desktop-tab-only-nav li ul {
          z-index:0;
        }
      
        #desktop-tab-only-nav li:hover ul {
            height: auto !important;
            opacity: 1 !important;
            z-index:1;
        }
        /***** Styles for the Sub Menu *********/
        
        #locations-list {
            display: block;
            opacity: 0;
            height: 0;
            width: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 61px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            transition: all 300ms;
            line-height: normal;
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        }
        
        #locations-list li a {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        #notifications-list {
            height: 0;
            opacity: 0;
            position: absolute;
            width: 280px;
            top: 61px;
            left: 0;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
            line-height: normal;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        
        #notifications-list li a {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        }
        
        #notifications-list .notification-icon-wrapper {
            padding: 5px 8px;
            color: #fff;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-right: 20px;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }
        
        #profile-dropdown-nav {
            margin: 0;
            width: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 60px;
            transition: all 300ms;
            opacity: 0;
            height: 0;
        }
        
        #profile-dropdown-nav li a {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        }
        
        #profile-dropdown-nav li a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
        
        #profile-dropdown-nav li:hover {
            background-color: #f1f2f6;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header id="header" class="header navbar-fixed clearfix">
        <div class="header-inner">
            <a href="index.php" title="Norbotion" class="cafe-logo">
                Norbotion
            </a>
            <ul id="desktop-tab-only-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">location_on</i>
                        <span class="notification-badge red">3</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="locations-list" class="collection with-header locations-list active">
                        <li class="collection-header">
                            <span class="new badge" data-badge-caption="">3</span>
                            <span style="font-weight: bold;padding-left: 10px"> Locations </span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Shollinganallur </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Taramani </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Karapakkam </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">mail</i>
                        <span class="notification-badge orange"> 4 </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">notifications</i>
                        <span class="notification-badge pink">5</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="notifications-list" class="collection with-header notifications-list active">
                        <li class="collection-header">
                            <p>
                                <span class="new badge">5</span> NOTIFICATIONS </p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper cyan">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span> New Zomoto Order palced
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper red">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span>New Zomoto Order palced
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper teal">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span>New Takeaway Order palced
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper deep-orange">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span>New Zomoto Order palced
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper amber">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span> New Uber Eat Order palced
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="profile-dropdown-nav" class="collection profile-dropdown-nav">
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="clearfix">
                                <i class="material-icons left">tag_faces</i>
                                <span> User profile </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="clearfix">
                                <i class="material-icons left">lock_outline</i>
                                <span> Logout </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you remove height zero from menu, with hover opacity equal to 1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Compiled and minified Materialize CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        header {
            width: 100%;
            height: 64px;
            background-color: #31373d;
            color: #fff;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding-top: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }

        header .header-inner {
            width: 95%;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        header .cafe-logo {
            color: #fff;
            font-size: 2.1rem;
        }
        /****** Styles for the Desktop Tab only topbar menu ********/

        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav {
            float: right;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav>li {
            width: 38px;
            height: 64px;
            line-height: 64px;
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav>li>a {
            color: #fff;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav>li>a:hover {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        header .notification-badge {
            position: absolute;
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 20px;
            font-size: 12px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            color: #fff;
            top: 5px;
            left: 12px;
        }

        ul#desktop-tab-only-nav>li:hover>ul {
            opacity: 1 !important;
        }
        /***** Styles for the Sub Menu *********/

        #locations-list {
            display: block;
            opacity: 0;
            width: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 61px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            transition: all 300ms;
            line-height: normal;
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        }

        #locations-list li a {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #notifications-list {
            opacity: 0;
            position: absolute;
            width: 280px;
            top: 61px;
            left: 0;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
            line-height: normal;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #notifications-list li a {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        }

        #notifications-list .notification-icon-wrapper {
            padding: 5px 8px;
            color: #fff;
            border-radius: 50%;
            margin-right: 20px;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }

        #profile-dropdown-nav {
            margin: 0;
            width: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 60px;
            transition: all 300ms;
            opacity: 0;
        }

        #profile-dropdown-nav li a {
            color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
        }

        #profile-dropdown-nav li a {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #profile-dropdown-nav li:hover {
            background-color: #f1f2f6;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header id="header" class="header navbar-fixed clearfix">
        <div class="header-inner">
            <a href="index.php" title="Norbotion" class="cafe-logo">
                Norbotion
            </a>
            <ul id="desktop-tab-only-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">location_on</i>
                        <span class="notification-badge red">3</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="locations-list" class="collection with-header locations-list active">
                        <li class="collection-header">
                            <span class="new badge" data-badge-caption="">3</span>
                            <span style="font-weight: bold;padding-left: 10px"> Locations </span>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Shollinganallur </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Taramani </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)"> Karapakkam </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">mail</i>
                        <span class="notification-badge orange"> 4 </span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">notifications</i>
                        <span class="notification-badge pink">5</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="notifications-list" class="collection with-header notifications-list active">
                        <li class="collection-header">
                            <p>
                                <span class="new badge">5</span> NOTIFICATIONS </p>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper cyan">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span> New Zomoto Order palced
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper red">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span>New Zomoto Order palced
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper teal">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span>New Takeaway Order palced
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper deep-orange">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span>New Zomoto Order palced
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <span class="left notification-icon-wrapper amber">
                                <i class="tiny material-icons">local_dining</i>
                            </span> New Uber Eat Order palced
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                    </a>
                    <ul id="profile-dropdown-nav" class="collection profile-dropdown-nav">
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="clearfix">
                                <i class="material-icons left">tag_faces</i>
                                <span> User profile </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="collection-item">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="clearfix">
                                <i class="material-icons left">lock_outline</i>
                                <span> Logout </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>

</html>
```